How can I display category inside ajax load more card
Category name not showing after clicking load more button...
I'm trying to add ajax load more button to show my projects with image, title and category. Image and title showing perfectly but the category not displaying. I think I've been wrong in my ajax code. Please help me. Thank you
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
var page = 2;
jQuery(function() {
        init isotope
        var $grid = jQuery('.grid');
        $grid.isotope({
                options
                itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                percentPosition: true,
        });
        jQuery('body').on('click', '.loadmore', function(e) {

                var data = {
                        'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
                        'page': page,
                        'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_projects"); ?>'
                };

                jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                        if (response != '') {
                                var $answer = jQuery(response);

                                //append items to grid
                                $grid.append($answer)
                                        .isotope('appended', $answer);

                                layaout on imagesLoaded
                                $grid.imagesLoaded(function() {
                                        $grid.isotope('layout');
                                });
                                page++;
                        else {
                                jQuery('.loadmore').text("No more Project!");
                        }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
        });
});

front-page.php
<?php
$terms = get_terms('project_category');
foreach ($terms as  $term) { ?>
        <li data-filter=".<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></li>
<?php  }
?>
</div>
<div class="filters-content">
        <div class="row grid">
                <?php
                $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'project',
                        'posts_per_page' => 6,
                        'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1), //page number 1 on load
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                );
                $query = new WP_Query($args);
                while ($query->have_posts()) {
                        $query->the_post();
                        $termsArray = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'project_category');
                        $termsSLug = "";
                        foreach ($termsArray as $term) {
                                $termsSLug .= $term->slug . ' ';
                        }
                ?>
                        <div class="single-portfolio col-sm-4  <?php echo  $termsSLug; ?>  grid-item">
                                <div class="item">
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="Work 1">
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="p-inner">
                                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                                </a>
                                                <div class="cat">
                                                        <?php
                                                        $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'project_category');
                                                        foreach ($terms as $term) {
                                                                $term_link = get_term_link($term);
                                                                echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>' . ' ';
                                                        }
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                <?php  }
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
        </div>
        
        <?php if ($query->max_num_pages >1) { ?>
                  <div class="button_load_more ">
                     <div class="btn_wrapper">
                     <a class="btn btn-default btn_style_more loadmore "href="#">Load More Projects</a>
                       </div>

functions.php
<?php

add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');
function load_posts_by_ajax_callback()
{
        check_ajax_referer('load_more_projects', 'security');
        $paged = $_POST['page'];

        $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'project',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => 6,
                'paged' => $paged,

        );
        $my_posts = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($my_posts->have_posts()) { ?>
                <?php
                while ($my_posts->have_posts()) {
                        $my_posts->the_post();

                        $termsArray = get_the_terms($post->ID, "project_category");
                        $termsSlug = ""; //initialize the variable that will contain the terms
                        foreach ($termsArray as $term) { // for each term
                                $termsSlug .= $term->slug . ' '; //create a string that has all the slugs
                        }
                ?>
                        <div class="single-portfolio col-sm-4  <?php echo  $termsSLug; ?>  grid-item">
                                <div class="item">
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="Work 1">
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="p-inner">
                                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                                </a>
                                                <div class="cat">
                                                        <?php
                                                        $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'project_category');
                                                        foreach ($terms as $term) {
                                                                $term_link = get_term_link($term);
                                                                echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>' . ' ';
                                                        }
                                                        ?>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                <?php  }
                ?>
<?php  }
        wp_die();
}

footer.php


Did you try with var page = 1? You could check in your browser the Ajax response for errors. Make sure that the category slug project_category is valid.

Hey I found that you missed some brackets, missed some closing tags. Please find attached updated code snippets

Line Number 32 - page++; after this missed }

var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
var page = 2;
jQuery(function() {
        init isotope
        var $grid = jQuery('.grid');
        $grid.isotope({
                options
                itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                percentPosition: true,
        });
        jQuery('body').on('click', '.loadmore', function(e) {

                var data = {
                        'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
                        'page': page,
                        'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_projects"); ?>'
                };

                jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                        if (response != '') {
                                var $answer = jQuery(response);

                                //append items to grid
                                $grid.append($answer)
                                        .isotope('appended', $answer);

                                layaout on imagesLoaded
                                $grid.imagesLoaded(function() {
                                        $grid.isotope('layout');
                                });
                                page++;
                        } else {
                                jQuery('.loadmore').text("No more Project!");
                        }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
        });
});

front-page.php

Line Number 42 Missed ?> closing php

<?php
$terms = get_terms('project_category');
foreach ($terms as  $term) { ?>
        <li data-filter=".<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></li>
<?php  }
?>
</div>
<div class="filters-content">
        <div class="row grid">
                <?php
                $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'project',
                        'posts_per_page' => 6,
                        'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1), //page number 1 on load
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                );
                $query = new WP_Query($args);
                while ($query->have_posts()) {
                        $query->the_post();
                        $termsArray = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'project_category');
                        $termsSLug = "";
                        foreach ($termsArray as $term) {
                                $termsSLug .= $term->slug . ' ';
                        }
                ?>
                        <div class="single-portfolio col-sm-4  <?php echo  $termsSLug; ?>  grid-item">
                                <div class="item">
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="Work 1">
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="p-inner">
                                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                                </a>
                                                <div class="cat">
                                                        <?php
                                                        $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'project_category');
                                                        foreach ($terms as $term) {
                                                                $term_link = get_term_link($term);
                                                                echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>' . ' ';
                                                        }
                                                        ?>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                <?php  }
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
        </div>
        
        <?php if ($query->max_num_pages >1) { ?>
                  <div class="button_load_more ">
                     <div class="btn_wrapper">
                     <a class="btn btn-default btn_style_more loadmore "href="#">Load More Projects</a>
                       </div>

